# Finding the number that's less than 90% of result set

Tags: data-analysis

Forgive if this sounds vague or poorly worded. I'm struggling to pinpoint the right terminology of what I'm looking to do. Hoping someone here can push me in the right direction.

So I have a set of numbers. Say:
$15, 22, 15, 10, 20, 20, 13, 13, 22, 23, 13, 22, 20, 8$

I'd like to know what would I need to do to calculate the number that is approximately Less Than or Equal to $90\%$ of each these numbers as a whole (but not less than $90$).

Just playing around I know I'd want 10 (is Less Than or equal to 13 out of 14 numbers) but I'm not sure how to solidly calculate this.

Any help would be great! =)

Answer (score 2):

The number that is approximately less than or equal to 90% of each of your numbers is called the 10th percentile. Another phrasing is that any number that is greater than or equal to x% of your numbers is in the xth percentile. The best way to figure that number out is to list your numbers in order from least to greatest, and find the number in the list where 10% of the numbers are less than it (or 90% of the numbers are greater than it).

Comment: Perfect! Percentile was the word I looking for. Thank you so much.